# Print background images and colors in IE without checking “Print background colors and images”

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, background

I have added a `media="print"` stylesheet, I have added `*{-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}`
But only chrome displays backgrounds (images and colors)! Is there a solution to fix it without checking “Print background colors and images” ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**As noted on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

As such it should not be relied upon, indeed support in Chrome is marked as 'Buggy', **all other browsers are *not* supported**, note that the use of the `-webkit-` vendor prefix denotes intended 'support' in webkit browsers, IE does not use the webkit engine.

Typically, you are not able to determine / override / code the option to print background colors and images. One approach is to utilise other properties / elements, such as using `img` elements for actual images, or using pseudo elements with extremely wide borders to mimic background colors. However, often neither is practical.

Unfortunately support of even the print or paged media modules accross browsers is terrible. Indeed, the CSS working group has a [**large discussion around the whole topic**](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/print-backgrounds)

Comment: In my case the possible solution is the first one "Do nothing"! Just users who will print should check the option to print backgrounds, in mozilla and IE!